# React Redux - dispatch action with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

To clearify I'm pretty newbie with the concept of react-redux. I try to dispatch an async action in the presentational comp. but this does not seem to work out.

### Container Component

```
const store = configureStore();

const Root: React.FC = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

## Presentational Component

```
interface AppProps {
    system: SystemState,
    updateSession: typeof updateSession,
    getLanguageThunk: any
}

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({system, updateSession, getLanguageThunk}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getLanguageThunk().then((res: any) => {
            console.log(res);
            i18n.init().then(
                () => i18n.changeLanguage(res.language));
       });
    }, []
);

    return (
            <div>
                <div className="app">
                    <TabBar/>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
    system: state.system
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateSession, getLanguageThunk })(App);
```

But the console everytime logs undefined. So I am doint something wrong here. Maybe some of u can help me out on here.

## Redux middleware

```
export const getLanguageThunk = (): ThunkAction<void, AppState, null, Action<string>> => async dispatch => {
    const language = await getLanguage();
    dispatch(
        updateSession({
            disableSwipe: false,
            language
        })
    )
};

async function getLanguage() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/language');
        return response.json();
    } catch {
        return { language: 'en_GB' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the language from `getLanguageThunk`, to be able to use it from promise in the `useEffect` method

```
export const getLanguageThunk = (): ThunkAction<void, AppState, null, Action<string>> => async dispatch => {
    const language = await getLanguage();
    dispatch(
        updateSession({
            disableSwipe: false,
            language
        })
    )
    return language;
};
```